# AppArmor blocking firefox on Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, firefox, apparmor

Using aa-genprof, I've attempted to generate a profile for Firefox, but AppArmor keeps blocking access to a connect capability when Firefox attempts to start, which throws an error :

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

The AppArmor denied message is:

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1579485118.392:135258): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect"
       profile="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh" pid=8529 comm="firefox" family="unix"
       sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="send receive connect" denied_mask="send connect"
       addr=none peer_addr="@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" peer="unconfined"`
```

I have attempted to re-run `aa-genprof` and detect this and allow it, but it is never detected by `aa-genprof`. Because of this permission not being allowed, Firefox will not open.

Is there any way I can hard code this permission into the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.firefox.firefox.sh` file? What line should I insert?

Comment: Try to add a rule that apply directly to firefox binary not the sh file

Comment: What is the output of `sudo aa-unconfined ` ? Is firefox listed there

Comment: Firefox is not listed there.